# Request to mongodb objects corresponding to the date range

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with the following example document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbb299f06229dddbaab553b"),
    "phone" : "+38 (031) 231-23-21",
    "date_call" : "2018-10-08",
    "adress_delivery" : "1",
    "quantity_concrete" : "1",
    "state" : "200",
    "comments" : "1",
    "is_order" : "n",
    "date_delivery" : "",
    "quantity_orders" : "",
    "summ_order" : "",
    "profit" : "",
    "id" : "0"
}
```

All I need to do is filter the data for the selected date range, for example, between 2018-01-08 and 2018-10-10 :

- **number of documents**
- **number of documents corresponding to the "is_order": "y"**

Tell me, please, how best to filter data?

- To load completely all data by the answer from AJAX and to filter
  already in complete method?
- Fully filter the data on the server? If on the server - tell me
  whether it can be done in one request? Or is it worth splitting a
  request, creating an array and sending a response?

Comment: are you using mongoose ?

Comment: In this case I'm not using mongoose but query will look something similar. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Did a bit of housekeeping, it should be `documents` instead of `collections`; MongoDB stores BSON _documents_, i.e. data records, in _collections_; the _collections_ in _databases_.

Answer (score 0):

**(1) number of documents between 2018-01-08 and 2018-10-10**

```
Model.find({
      "date_call":{
                  "$lte":"2018-10-10",
                  "$gte":"2018-01-08"
                  }
     },function(err,data){
     if(err){ return res.status(500).json({status:'error',errors:err});}
     if(!err && data){ return res.status(200).json({stauts:'success',data:data});}
});
```

**(2) number of documents corresponding to the "is_order": "y"**

```
Model.find({
          "is_order": "y",
          "date_call":{
                      "$lte":"2018-10-10",
                      "$gte":"2018-01-08"
                      }
         },function(err,data){
         if(err){ return res.status(500).json({status:'error',errors:err});}
         if(!err && data){ return res.status(200).json({stauts:'success',data:data});}
    });
```